# Regex search to look ahead

Tags: regex

Using PCRE

Text:

```
<xsi:placeOrderResult list="test:value">1469120938131</placeOrderResult></soapenv:Body>
```

Would like to match any alpha-numeric characters following (but not including) the "<" character, UP to and including the ":" character, but the colon must be found before the FIRST ">" is found.

Expected result for above would be:

```
<placeOrderResult list="test:value">1469120938131</placeOrderResult></soapenv:Body>
```

The first part is fairly straight forward - what I can't figure out is the "colon must be found before the first >".

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: Sure, this is as close as I was able to get: (?<=<)\w+?:    However, it does match what I want removed but it doesn't check to ensure that the : occurred before a closing bracket. I think this regex will work ok because in the application I'm using, I have the option of SELECTING only the matched string, or REMOVING only the matched string so I can just use the removing function and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=<)(\w+?:)(?=[^<]*?>)
```

https://regex101.com/r/yY7yD7

```
$re = "/(?<=<)(\\w+?:)(?=[^<]*?>)/"; 
$str = "#Text:\n<xsi:placeOrderResult list=\"test:value\">1469120938131</placeOrderResult></soapenv:Body>\n\n#Expected result\n<placeOrderResult list=\"test:value\">1469120938131</placeOrderResult></soapenv:Body>"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```

Regex Explained:

- `(?<=<)` - Positive Lookbehind - Matches the character `<`.
- `\w+?` match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_] between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
- `:` matches the character `:` literally
- `(?=[^<]*?>)` Positive lookahead - Matches every character not `<` between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]. until it reache the character `>`.

When you subtitute nothing, "", for the captured regex, it gives your expected result:

```
<placeOrderResult list="test:value">1469120938131</placeOrderResult></soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That regex selects the entire text in my example though - all of this: <xsi:placeOrderResult list="test:value">1469120938131</placeOrderResult></soapenv:Body>

Comment: Though my example did work on both php and regex101, I updated it to include what you wanted `check to ensure that the : occurred before a closing bracket`. If you think that this doesn't work, please use the regex101 link, and show me an example of how it isn't working.